# iPhone 7+, ios 11.2: Depth data delivery is not supported in the current configuration

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice, avcaptureoutput

This bug is driving me mad. I'm trying to produce the absolute minimal code to get `AVDepthData` from an iPhone 7+ using its DualCam.

I have this code:

```
//
//  RecorderViewController.swift
//  ios-recorder-app


import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class RecorderViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!

    @IBAction func onTapTakePhoto(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let capturePhotoOutput = self.capturePhotoOutput else { return }

        let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()

        photoSettings.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true //Error

        capturePhotoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)

    }

    var session: AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var capturePhotoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: { _ in })

        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .depthData, position: .back)

        do {
            print(captureDevice!)
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)

            self.capturePhotoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            self.capturePhotoOutput?.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true //Error

            self.session = AVCaptureSession()
            self.session?.addInput(input)

            self.videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session!)
            self.videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            self.videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            previewView.layer.addSublayer(self.videoPreviewLayer!)

            self.session?.addOutput(self.capturePhotoOutput!)
            self.session?.startRunning()

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

extension RecorderViewController : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        print(photo.depthData)

    }


}
```

If I comment out the lines that are marked with "Error" the code works as I would expect, and prints `nil` for `depthData`.

However, leaving the lines as they are, I get an exception. The error message states: `AVCapturePhotoOutput setDepthDataDeliveryEnabled:] Depth data delivery is not supported in the current configuration`.

How do I change the "current configuration" so that depth delivery is supported?

I've watched this video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/ which was helpful, and I believe I've followed the exact steps required to make this work.

Any tips would be gratefully received!

Comment: Use `var photoSettings ` instead of `let photoSettings `

Comment: I changed every use of a `let` to a `var` and the exception still happens. It seems to happen at this stage: `self.capturePhotoOutput?.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true //Error`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things that I needed to fix.

1. Set a `sessionPreset` to a format that supports depth, such as `.photo`.
2. Add the cameraPhotoOutput to session before setting `.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true`.

Here is my minimal code for getting depth with photos:

```
//
//  RecorderViewController.swift
//  ios-recorder-app
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class RecorderViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!

    @IBAction func onTapTakePhoto(_ sender: Any) {

        guard var capturePhotoOutput = self.capturePhotoOutput else { return }

        var photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoSettings.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true

        capturePhotoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)

    }

    var session: AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var capturePhotoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: { _ in })

        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back)

        print(captureDevice!.activeDepthDataFormat)

        do{
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)

            self.capturePhotoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

            self.session = AVCaptureSession()
            self.session?.beginConfiguration()
            self.session?.sessionPreset = .photo
            self.session?.addInput(input)

            self.videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session!)
            self.videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            self.videoPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.bounds
            self.previewView.layer.addSublayer(self.videoPreviewLayer!)

            self.session?.addOutput(self.capturePhotoOutput!)
            self.session?.commitConfiguration()
            self.capturePhotoOutput?.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true
            self.session?.startRunning()
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

extension RecorderViewController : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        print(photo.depthData)
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer a lot. However, I found that if I write `self.capturePhotoOutput?.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true` before `self.session?.addOutput(self.capturePhotoOutput!)`, the app will crash saying `-[AVCapturePhotoOutput setDepthDataDeliveryEnabled:] Depth data delivery is not supported in the current configuration'`. Do you know why this happens?